# Double precision floating point. Why is the maximum exponent 1023

Tags: floating-point, binary, numbers, double

When we have a binary Intel processor and a double precision float represented by 64 bits of which 1 bit for the sign, 52 bits for mantissa and 11 bits for the exponent.

I do not understand why the `e_max = 2^10 - 1 = 1023` shouldn't it be 2^11 since 11 bits are dedicated to it.

How does it follow from this that the smallest represented float is in the order of 10^(-308) and the largest 10^(308)?

Thanks for any clarification or explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... why the e_max = 2^10 - 1 = 1023 shouldn't it be 2^11 since 11 bits are dedicated to it.

No.  Consider negative exponents.

With [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) encoding, the encoded number has a *biased exponent*, an 11-bit unsigned integer from 0 to 2047.  (Biased exponents of 0 and 2047 have special meaning.)

After applying an offset of -1023, the encoding has an *(unbiased) exponent* in the range [-1023 ... 1024]. (Again, the end-points have additional special meaning.) This encodes very large values like 10<sup>308</sup> and tiny ones like 10<sup>-308</sup>.

---

The original design of the encoding of binary64 could have used an 11-bit *signed* integer for the exponent, in some [signed integer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations), yet that had disadvantages.  With a *biased* exponent we have advantages:

- About that time signed integer encoding of 2's complement, 1s' compliment and sign-magnitude machines existed.  Selecting one of those 3 for the *exponent* would disadvantage the other 2.
- If we view the entire floating point encoding as a sign-magnitude  integer, the order of floating point values from least to greatest is preserved.
- The bias selected (-1203) provides for about as many absolute values greater than 1.0 as less than 1.0.  The bias selected slightly has more more absolute values > 1.0 than < 1.0.  This allows 1.0/max to be represented as non-zero (some sub-normal value).  It also allows 1.0/*normal_values* to not overflow.  Using one of the 3 popular signed integer encodings would not provide this unless it too, had a bias.